# How to determine contrasts in combinations of categorical variables with emmeans

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, lsmeans

I have some data with a continuous outcome that is measured among 4 categorical variables: treatment group, gender, collection date, and sub_type. Gender is M/F, collection date can just be Mon/Wed, and sub_type is one of A, B, C, D.

There are 10 treatment groups and one control. Treatment groups 1-5 were tested on sub_type A, while treatment groups 6-10 were tested on sub_type B. All treatment groups were tested on both Mon and Wed, and all treatment groups were tested on Males and females. The control was tested on all sub types A, B, C, and D.

I am mainly interested in comparing each treatment group mean to control (expressed as a difference with 95% CI), within the other variables groups (e.g. Males on Monday in sub type A). I have simply set the data up as a linear model with each covariate added as an interaction term.

```
mod <- lm(value ~ group*study_day*gender*sub_type, data = dd)
```

and then determined the contrasts between each treatment group and control using `emmeans`

```
res <- emmeans(mod , ~ group | study_day*gender*sub_type,
             specs = trt.vs.ctrlk ~ group,
             fac.reduce = function(coefs) apply(coefs,
                                                2, mean),
             by = c("study_day", "gender", "sub_type")
```

I obtain contrasts between each group and placebo, which is what I want. However, given that contrasts for cases where a group was not tested on a sub type (e.g. group 1 with subtype D), the contrasts are reported as "nonEst". I don't actually want this contrast, but I am unsure whether this means I am just setting up the model wrong in the first place. To me, adding the variables simply as non-interaction covariates `lm(out ~ group + gender + study_day...` doesn't necessarily make sense either. I should note that originally I tested these all as individual pairwise t-tests, but thought that I should be using emmeans to consider the degrees of freedom from the overall model. I thought of including the additional covariates as random effects, but I thought that since I am only interested in the specific levels of these covariates (e.g. A, B, C, D subtypes), including these as random effects was not necessary.

Below is an excerpt from the emmeans results.

[image]

Below is the code used to set up the dummy data (there was probably a simpler way to do this):

```
library(tidyr)
set.seed(10473)

gender <- c("M", "F")
study_day <- c("Mon", "Wed")
sub_type <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
group <- c(1:10, "PBO")

dat <- expand.grid(gender, study_day, sub_type, group,stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
names(dat) <- c("gender", "study_day", "sub_type", "group")
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(n = 5) %>%
  uncount(n) %>%
  mutate(out = rnorm(n = nrow(.),
                     mean = 2,
                     sd = 1))  %>%
  mutate(out = case_when(
    group %in% c(1:5) & sub_type %in% c("C", "D") ~ NA_real_,
    group %in% c(6:10) & sub_type %in% c("A", "B") ~ NA_real_,
    TRUE ~ out
  )) %>%
  filter(!is.na(out)) %>%
  mutate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a nested fixed-effects structure, where `group` is nested in `sub_type`. Did not `emmeans` auto-detect this? You can make this structure explicit by omitting any term where `group` does not interact with `sub_type`:

```
mod2 <- lm(value ~ (sub_type + sub_type:group)*study_day*gender, data = dd)
```

`emmeans()` should detect this nesting and automatically bypass the cases where `group` and `sub_type` are mismatches.

I also recommend looking at the model summary and seeing if you can omit a bunch of other interactions from the model.

Comment: I believe this could be nested-fixed effect where `group` is nested within `sub_type`, except for the fact the `group == 1` is the same group across all sub types...

Comment: Maybe just go with what you had before? The non-estimability checks are serving you in that they are identifying the cases that don't make sense and that you should ignore.

Comment: Ok thank you, I just wasn't sure if you should limit/subset your model so that there are no non-estimable results, but that would reduce the degrees of freedom in that case. I will keep what I had before. In this situation, should p-values be adjusted for multiple comparisons? Or is that already taken into account with the standard error of the complete model.

Comment: Hmmmm, Tukey adjustments are done by default, but the adjustment does *not* change if there are non-estimable comparisons.

Comment: hmm so I might just be better off using `pairs(..., adjust = 'none')`  and then doing a bonferroni adjustment (or some other method) after.

Comment: @Gmiller I was wrong -- I have discovered that `p.adjust()` *does* adapt to the number of estimable cases. But I am not 100% convinced that it is getting it right in emmeans because of the way the adjustments are organized in the code.

Comment: @Gmiller I have made all p-value and conf-limit adjustments be adaptable to the number of estimable cases in each by group. If you have **emmeans** version 1.8.7 or lower, you will need to install it from [GitHub](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans).

Comment: Ah nice thank you. I ended up just pulling the results out myself, and then doing the same adjustment by group after the fact, but i will check out your contribution on github!